# How to convert bit string into integer?

Tags: c, bit

Is there any way to convert a 2'scomplement bit string into a integer?
I think it's easy enough for positive numbers, but as for negative numbers I'm a little confused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bits2Integer(char bitString[]){
     int value = 1;
     int power = 1;
     int constantIncrement = 2;
     if(bitString[0] == 0) {
          for(int i = 32; i >= 0; i--){
               if(bitString[i] == 1){
                    value = value + power;
                    power = power * constantIncrement;
               }
               else {
                    power = power * constantIncrement;
               }
     }
}
```

Oh, and I don't want to use any other library/resource other than stdio.h.

Comment: "I don't know if it works" - why don't you try testing it?

Comment: you made it and you don't know if it works ?

Comment: 0)`int value = 1;` --> `int value = 0;` 1) `int i = 32;` --> `int i = 31;` 2) `bitString[i] == 1` --> `bitString[i] == '1'` 3) `return value;` add to last

Comment: I didn't see all the comments before I refreshed the page, sorry guys

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm running on Windows, so I'm only running the codes through my brain. Sorry for the confusion. If you don't mind me asking, is there a functional C compiler for Windows?

Comment: @Leon: Absolutely.  Visual Studio is free (probably easiest option), or you could run GCC via MinGW or Cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the best way

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bits2Integer(char bitString[]){
     int ret = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
          if(bitString[i] == '1')
            ret |= 1 << (31-i);

     return ret;
}
```

Bitwise operations rule the world :)

Remember that you can't have `33` bits.

Comment: Hi, that would work perfectly! Does that also work for 2's complement too?
I'm very new to C, so still learning all the bit manipulations and tricks.

Comment: @Leon The question is what you mean by the two's complement. If you have a negative number in form of bits written in a string, and you'd like to turn it into an integer, then yes, this will work for this too. If I've answered your question, please, tick the green "OK" on the left side to accept it :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I understand the logic though, I'll write it in my own version :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you support your statement? It works perfectly, tested with IdeOne.com.

Comment: 0) `{` remove or add `}` 1) `1 << i` should be `1 << (31-i)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY now I see. Yes, you're right. Didn't validate the results, though :)